# Understanding the improved version of Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API in my project and came across this link:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3270
The code is attached in a zip file on this link. The specific part I didn't understand is this piece:

```
input_graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=input_graph):
    score = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1917, 90), name="Postprocessor/convert_scores")
    expand = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1917, 1, 4), name="Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1")
    for node in input_graph.as_graph_def().node:
        if node.name == "Postprocessor/convert_scores":
            score_def = node
        if node.name == "Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1":
            expand_def = node

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        dest_nodes = ['Postprocessor/convert_scores','Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1']

        edges = {}
        name_to_node_map = {}
        node_seq = {}
        seq = 0
        for node in od_graph_def.node:
            n = _node_name(node.name)
            name_to_node_map[n] = node
            edges[n] = [_node_name(x) for x in node.input]
            node_seq[n] = seq
            seq += 1

        for d in dest_nodes:
            assert d in name_to_node_map, "%s is not in graph" % d

        nodes_to_keep = set()
        next_to_visit = dest_nodes[:]
        while next_to_visit:
            n = next_to_visit[0]
            del next_to_visit[0]
            if n in nodes_to_keep:
                continue
            nodes_to_keep.add(n)
            next_to_visit += edges[n]

        nodes_to_keep_list = sorted(list(nodes_to_keep), key=lambda n: node_seq[n])

        nodes_to_remove = set()
        for n in node_seq:
            if n in nodes_to_keep_list: 
                continue
            nodes_to_remove.add(n)
        nodes_to_remove_list = sorted(list(nodes_to_remove), key=lambda n: node_seq[n])

        keep = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
        for n in nodes_to_keep_list:
            keep.node.extend([copy.deepcopy(name_to_node_map[n])])

        remove = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
        remove.node.extend([score_def])
        remove.node.extend([expand_def])
        for n in nodes_to_remove_list:
            remove.node.extend([copy.deepcopy(name_to_node_map[n])])

        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            tf.import_graph_def(keep, name='')
        with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
            tf.import_graph_def(remove, name='')
```

It reduces time required for processing per image by correctly assigning operations to GPU and CPU. I got the basic idea that it is trying to distribute operations on CPU and GPU but explanation on the two graphs, their structure and working would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of this code is:

- It creates a graph with 2 placeholders `'Postprocessor/convert_scores'` and `'Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1'`.
- Converts it to a `graph_def` and keeps the nodes corresponding to the placeholders.

  - Those 2 nodes correspond to the 1917 boxes the model outputs, the first one is the class probabilities the second one is the box coordinates.
- It creates a second graph and loads the trained model.
- It lists all the nodes in the graph and how they are connected to each other.
- Lists all the nodes connected to `'Postprocessor/convert_scores'` and `'Postprocessor/ExpandDims_1'`, and store them in the keep list.
- Lists all the nodes not in `nodes_to_keep_list` and stores them in `nodes_to_remove_list`.
- It then creates a graph def and fills it with a copy of all the `nodes_to_keep_list` nodes.
- Then a second graph def with a copy of all the `nodes_to_remove_list` nodes.
- Finally it loads both graph defs, the first one with device `'/gpu:0'`, the second `'/cpu:0'`.

The aim of this, as stated by the author, is to run the CNN on the GPU, and the postprocessing on the CPU because it is much faster there.
If you look at mobilenet+SSD you'll see that the model outputs a bunch of boxes (1917) and then there is a rather complex (from a graph standpoint at least) post processing done on those boxes to provide the final output (`detection_boxes`, `detection_scores`, `detection_classes`, `num_detections`).

It's not visible in this piece of code, but the placeholders are later used to insert the output of the `keep` graph in the `remove` graph. The execution is performed in 2 steps (2 calls to `sess.run()`)

```
(score, expand) = sess.run([score_out, expand_out], feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={score_in:score, expand_in: expand})
print 'Iteration %d: %.3f sec'%(i, time.time()-start_time)
```

**EDIT**

The `1917` value comes from the original graph, with a different model it will be a different value, but even different nodes etc... That's why this solution is more a hack than a real solution, because it needs to be tailored to each new model you want to apply it to ...

I looked at this graph a little while ago, I think the model outputs a bunch of boxes of a certain size or aspect ratio, and an other bunch at a different aspect ratio etc, all this is merged together and you end up with this `1917` boxes figure.

`ExpandDims` is just the name of the operation, as it was not named in the graph. the `_1` is there because there was already one in the graph in this scope probably. As to why these nodes specifically, it's just an arbitrary choice of the author, which he made after investigating on these performance issues. Basically the slow part is after these nodes. But he could have selected slightly different nodes, for instance before the `ExpandDims` operation it would have performed done the same thing. The actual purpose of these specific nodes has nothing to do with what he's doing here. And in the case of `ExpandDims`, it is a pretty mundane operation, just adding a dimension of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still don't understand why the placeholders are hard-coded to value 1917.Does this number ever change? Also, if we are just creating placeholders, what is the need to create a new input graph? Can't we just create them inside detection graph? Also, what are these 'convert_scores' and 'expand_dims' node doing? Could you clarify?

Comment: @user8652313 if you are using ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 model like the link, you may look into neural network model. My guess is that the 1917 is maximum detected bounding boxes. 90 is number of classes (ref: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/omz_models_public_ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.html).